# What resources can be used to get reliable information about recommender systems and using time feature?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, recommender-system

I am working on a recommender system that suggests games to users based on their playing history. So far, I have not used the period - when the user played specific games. I want to test my performance with it but I have not been able to find anything useful about it.

Specifically, splitting data is my primary concern. It should not be done with a random shuffle but I am not sure if just a simple `take()` function is enough. The data should be ordered by date. There was a concept about windowing that I saw but did not get the idea very well.

I work with Tensorflow so any suggestions if, being linked to it would be highly appreciated.